# How to single-out a cell in a table?

Tags: java

Im trying to be able to find a cell that the user inputs. I have made table thats like excel and I want to know how to find the cell, of what the user inputs. For example, if the user inputs 1a I would read through my table and find 1a. Thats what I need help. I need to know how to do this because later I need to know how to input numbers into that singled-out cell like if 1a =7 i would go to the 1a cell and inside that cell print out 7.

This is the code that I have so far:
public class Spreadsheat {

```
private int xVal = 137;
private int yVal = 1;
private int[][] table = new int [20][20];
private char yaxis = 'A';
private int xaxis = 0;


public Spreadsheat(){
    for(int i = 0; i < xVal; i++){
        System.out.print("-");
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.print(" |");
    for(int i = 0; i < 17; i++){
        System.out.print("| " + yaxis + "\t" + "|" );
        yaxis = (char) (yaxis + 1);
    }

    System.out.println();
    for(int i = 0; i < xVal; i++){
        System.out.print("-");
    }

    System.out.println();
    for(int j = 0; j <10;j++){
        System.out.print(" " + xaxis + "|");
        for(int i = 0; i < 17; i++){
            System.out.print("|" + "\t" + "|" );
        }

        System.out.println();
        xaxis = xaxis + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of explanation, I will assume the call to change the spreadsheet is through a method like this:

```
public void changeSheet (String inputLocation, int newData)
{
    int xPos = inputLocation.charAt(0) - '0';
    int yPos = inputLocation.charAt(1) - 'a';
    table[xPos][yPos] = newData;
}
```

The user input is inputLocation, and the new value is newData.  To get the x and y values of the array from that input, we just treat the chars in inputLocation like ints and subtract either '0' or 'a' to start in the correct index.  One caveat, I'm assuming that the inputLocation has a length of two and the number does not exceed nine (it looks like it currently goes from 0-9). If the number will exceed nine, you should substring out the number section of the number letter pair and use the Integer.parseInt(String s) function to get the xPos value (Don't subtract '0' then, because the number will already start at 0).

Also, while your letters count off properly, it looks like your numbers just list off as zero for every location.  Also, you have the x-axis being counted with letters and the y-axis being counted with numbers, while your variable names make it sound like it should be the other way around.  I may have just misread what you were asking for, but I hope this helps you out!